# Creating New Select option at each time

Tags: javascript, json

I want to reset new values each time in the option list created JSON by the line:

```
var o=document.createElement("option");
document.getElementById("shipTo").options.add(o); 
o.text= address[i];
```

But new option values are added in the list I want the no previous in the option:

```
var counter;
function GetAddress() {
    var customerId = document.getElementById("invoiceTo").value;
    var xml;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
            var address = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
            document.getElementById("billingAddress").value = address[0];
            document.getElementById("shipAddress").value = address[0];
            if (counter == 1) { {
                    for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
                        var removeMe = document.getElementById(o[i]);
                        removeMe.parentNode.removeChild(removeMe);
                        var o = document.createElement("option");
                        document.getElementById("shipTo").options.add(o);
                        o.text = address[i];
                    }
                }
            } else if (counter != 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
                    var o = document.createElement("option");
                    document.getElementById("shipTo").options.add(o);
                    o.text = address[i];
                }
            }
            counter = 1;
        }
        alert(counter);
    }
    xml.open("GET", "GenerateInvoice?customerId=" + customerId, true);
    xml.send();
}
```

Comment: You want to replace all existing options with the new options returned by your XHR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the options first:

```
var oDDL = document.getElementById("shipTo");
while (oDDL.options.length > 0)
    oDDL.options.remove(0);
```

Comment: thnx...for the idea but its not working...displaying the select option list with the old record

Comment: Cheers, I see you are pretty new to Stack Overflow and never accepted an answer so please choose the best answer (here and in other questions of yours) and mark as accepted by ticking the empty V icon to the left. Happy programming!

Comment: @VivekTiwari what? Sorry, no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to clear all the old options from the select element, before adding new options.

simply set options.length = 0;

example:

```
 var o = document.createElement("option");
 theSelect.options.length = 0;
 o.text = '400';                    
 theSelect.options.add(o);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asaf/77sqX/4/

Comment: thnx...for the idea but its not working...displaying the select option list with the old record

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetAddress()
{
var customerId = document.getElementById("invoiceTo").value;
var xml;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xml.onreadystatechange= function()
{
if(xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200)
{
var address= JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
document.getElementById("billingAddress").value=address[0];
document.getElementById("shipAddress").value= address[0];
var oDDL = document.getElementById("shipTo");//ship to id of the select in jsp
while (oDDL.options.length > 0)
{
oDDL.options.remove(0);//clears selects option each time
}
for(var i=0;i<address.length;i++)
{
var o = document.createElement("option");//creates optin
document.getElementById("shipTo").options.add(o);//adds option in the list
o.text= address[i];//inserts text in the option
}
}
}
xml.open("GET","GenerateInvoice?customerId="+customerId,true);
xml.send();
}
```

Comment: this is the final code that is working fine after using the solution provided